# How to stop TFS from getting code During a Build?

Tags: tfs, get, workflow, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2010.  I want some task to happen on a Solution that has already been built.  I DO NOT want to "get" any code, just leave what is there.  Is there anyway in my workflow, or anything else, to prevent TFS from getting any code?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do.  TFS doesn't do a "get" automatically (with one awful exception, "get latest on checkout", which should probably be turned off.)  Do you want to avoid other people checking in to this solution also?

Comment: You might have had an answer sooner if you had specified that you were talking about TFS Team Builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: don't use the "SyncWorkspace" task in the xaml workflow.